# Creating a custom class and linking to Main class

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, oop

I pretty much just want to create a separate class for my lists of words instead of cluttering my main class. Everything works fine if the array is in my Main Class. My problem is Im not sure how Im suppose to create the Array custom class and then link it to the main class. Here's what I have so far

```
package  {

public class RandomText  {


    public function RandomText() {
        var randomKill:Array = new Array("Goats",
                      "Bananas",
                      "Cows",
                      "a Printer",
                      "Pineapples",
                      "a Toothbrush")


    }

}
```

}

This is the one in my Main Class, but I'm not sure how I can link the Array class to this one. I kept getting an error saying Property length not found on RandomText and there is no default value at Main/moveCell().
Thanks a lot in advance!

```
 for (var i:int = 0; i < group.length; i++)
             {
                 var cell:Cell = Cell(group[i]);
                 if (cell.hitTestObject(island))
                 {
                     cell.parent.removeChild(cell);
                     group.splice(i,1);

                     score++;
                     //trace("hit me");

                     var randomText = new RandomText();
                      randomIndex =  Math.random () * randomText.length;
                     txtWordDisplay.text = "Killed by " + randomText[randomIndex]

                 }


             }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable 'randomKill' is stuck inside your Constructor scope.
In the example below, you need randomKill to be an attribute of the object:

```
package  {

public class RandomText  {   
    public var randomKill:Array = new Array("Goats",
                  "Bananas",
                  "Cows",
                  "a Printer",
                  "Pineapples",
                  "a Toothbrush");
     }
}

// -- You access 'randomKill' like this: 
var randomText = new RandomText();
randomIndex =  Math.random () * randomText.randomKill.length;
txtWordDisplay.text = "Killed by " + randomText.randomKill[randomIndex];
```

Comment: It's perfect! I can finally get some sleep, thank you so much!